# use the data from cloud object storage to jupyter noteboon in watson studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

I have a cloud object storage in IBM cloud and a bucket inside it. there are .wav files inside the bucket, and I have established a connection to my project in watson studio, I have added the data asset too. but I am not able to insert the data into python jupyter notebook. I only get the insert the credential in the find add data option, not the data as a streaming object. I used to do it before some days. I am using a lite version and my account free trial for a mont is valid till 12th Aug 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is being enabled again, in the meantime you can use the code snippet below to read the `.wav` file as a StreamingBody

```
import types
import pandas as pd
from botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3

def __iter__(self): return 0
os_client= ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
ibm_api_key_id='<IBM_API_KEY_ID>',
ibm_auth_endpoint="<IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT>",
config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
endpoint_url='<ENDPOINT>')

 # Your data file was loaded into a botocore.response.StreamingBody object.
 # Please read the documentation of ibm_boto3 and pandas to learn more about the possibilities to load the data.
 # ibm_boto3 documentation: https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-python/
 # pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/
 streaming_body_1 = os_client.get_object(Bucket='<BUCKET>', Key='myfile.wav')['Body']
 # add missing __iter__ method, so pandas accepts body as file-like object
if not hasattr(streaming_body_1, "__iter__"): streaming_body_1.__iter__ = types.MethodType( __iter__, streaming_body_1 )
```

You can read more details about reading objects from COS to the runtime's local filesystem in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629588/importing-scripts-into-a-notebook-in-ibm-watson-studio/57657568#57657568)