# Importing scripts into a notebook in IBM WATSON STUDIO

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I am doing PCA on CIFAR 10 image on IBM WATSON Studio Free version so I uploaded the python file for downloading the CIFAR10 on the studio

pic below. 
[image]

But when I trying to import `cache` the following error is showing.
pic below-
[image]

After spending some time on google I find a solution but I can't understand it. 
link 
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/add-script-to-notebook.html

```
the solution is as follows:- 
Click the Add Data icon (Shows the Add Data icon), and then browse the script file or drag it into your notebook sidebar.

Click in an empty code cell in your notebook and then click the Insert to code link below the file. Take the returned string, and write to a file in the file system that comes with the runtime session.

To import the classes to access the methods in a script in your notebook, use the following command:

For Python:

from <python file name> import <class name>
```

I can't understand this line

` and write to a file in the file system that comes with the runtime session.``

Where can I find the file that comes with runtime session? Where is the file system located?

Can anyone plz help me in this with the details where to find that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the import error because the script that you are trying to import is not available in your Python runtime's local filesystem. The files (`cache.py`, `cifar10.py`, etc.) that you uploaded are uploaded to the object storage bucket associated with the Watson Studio project. To use those files you need to make them available to the Python runtime for example by downloading the script to the runtimes local filesystem.

UPDATE: In the meanwhile there is an option to directly insert the StreamingBody objects. This will also have all the required credentials included. You can skip to `writing it to a file in the local runtime filesystem` section of this answer if you are using `insert StreamingBody object` option.

[image]

Or,

You can use the code snippet below to read the script in a StreamingBody object:

```
import types
import pandas as pd
from botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3

def __iter__(self): return 0
os_client= ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
ibm_api_key_id='<IBM_API_KEY_ID>',
ibm_auth_endpoint="<IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT>",
config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
endpoint_url='<ENDPOINT>')

# Your data file was loaded into a botocore.response.StreamingBody object.
# Please read the documentation of ibm_boto3 and pandas to learn more about the possibilities to load the data.
# ibm_boto3 documentation: https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-python/
# pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/
streaming_body_1 = os_client.get_object(Bucket='<BUCKET>', Key='cifar.py')['Body']
# add missing __iter__ method, so pandas accepts body as file-like object
if not hasattr(streaming_body_1, "__iter__"): streaming_body_1.__iter__ = types.MethodType( __iter__, streaming_body_1 )
```

And then write it to a file in the local runtime filesystem.

```
f = open('cifar.py', 'wb')
f.write(streaming_body_1.read())
```

This opens a file with write access and calls the `write` method to write to the file. You should then be able to simply import the script.

```
import cifar
```

Note: You can get the credentials like `IBM_API_KEY_ID` for the file by clicking on the `Insert credentials` option on the drop-down menu for your file.

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions that op found](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/add-script-to-notebook.html) miss one crucial line of code. I followed them and was able to import modules but wasn't able to use any functions or classes in those modules. This was fixed by closing the files after writing. This part in the instrucitons:

```
f = open('<myScript>.py', 'wb')
f.write(streaming_body_1.read())
```

should instead be (at least this works in my case):

```
f = open('<myScript>.py', 'wb')
f.write(streaming_body_1.read())
f.close()
```

Hopefully this helps someone.